# Bolt hole reinforcement? For barrel bolts

Tags: bolts, hardware

I would like to drill a hole in the wall for a barrel bolt, similar to the photo below:

http://www.aoml.noaa.gov/hrd/shutters/ply4.jpg

However, instead of having a bare hole in the wall, is there a piece of hardware I can buy to fit a metal reinforcement into the hole? The barrel bolt would slide into this metal reinforcement.

I am asking because I don't know if such things exist.

Thanks.

Comment: "insert nut" -- item C at http://www.leevalley.com/en/hardware/page.aspx?p=44203&cat=3,43576,61994,44203  You'd possibly want to drill out the threads on the interior.

Answer (score 2):

I would buy a bolt that includes the part you seek

[image]
[image]
[image]

OK, it might not be exactly what you thought you needed, but it is what everyone else uses to securely locate the bolt end in the frame.

If you have an electric hand drill you can easily make one of these yourself if necessary.